# What is the purpose of these Unix groups?

Tags: macos, terminal

I see the following groups on my user id when working in terminal:

```
$ id | tr ',' '\n' | grep apple
702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
395(com.apple.access_ftp)
398(com.apple.access_screensharing)
```

What is the purpose of these groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
>
> com.apple.sharepoint.group.2

Directory Services.  These groups for for the permissions of sharepoints (not to be confused with [Microsoft SharePoint](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/collaboration)); shared folders, volumes, drives, etc.

> com.apple.access_ftp

FTP file sharing.  This defines the access rights/permissions for FTP (File Transfer Protocol).  It a long since deprecated protocol/service and you should be using `scp` instead.

> com.apple.access_screensharing

Remote Screen Sharing.  This defines the access rights/permissions for screen sharing (or "remote control")